# RabbitMQ: setReturnListner handleBasicReturn nt getting called for undelivered messages

Tags: rabbitmq

For one of the requirement we need to keep track of queue depth and successfully processed messages. The idea is to publish messages and get a list of successful and failed messages. To simulate the requirement I did the following

1. Publish the messages with Mandatory and Immediate flag sent  channel.basicPublish 'exchange' ,'rKey',true,false, props,"Hello World".bytes
2. The consumer consumes even marked ( I have put numbers from 1..10 as marked value in header of each messages)  and does not ACKS odd numbered messages.
3. I have implemented setReturnListnere in the publisher to capture undelivered messages.

While am able to get the number of unack messages via Rabbmitmqctl list_queues messages_unacknowledged, somehow my handleBasicReturn method does not gets called. Am in missing something.

Code snippets:

Producer:

```
channel.setReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {
    public void handleBasicReturn(int replyCode, String replyText, String exchange,
                                  String routingKey, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                  byte[] body) 
            throws IOException {
        println "Debugging messages!!!!"
        println "The details of returned messages are ${replyText} from  ${exchange} with routingKey as ${routingKey} with properties"
    }
});

println " queuename is ${dec.queue} and consumerCount is ${dec.consumerCount} messageCount is ${dec.messageCount}"
(1..10).each {
    println "Sending file ${i}....."
    def headers = new HashMap<String,Object>()
    headers.put "operatiion","scp"
    headers.put "dest","joker.dk.mach.com"
    headers.put "id", i
    println headers

    BasicProperties props = new BasicProperties(null, null, headers, null, null, null, null, null,null, null, null, null,null, null)
                    channel.basicPublish 'exchange' ,'rKey',true,false, props,"Hello Worls".bytes                                
    i++                         
}
channel.close()
```

Consumer:

```
while (true) {
    def delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
    def headers = delivery?.properties?.headers
    def id = headers.get("id")
    println "Received message:"
    println " ${id.toString()}"

    if( id % 2 == 0){
        channel.basicAck delivery.envelope.deliveryTag, false                
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this explanation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/faq.html#mandatory-flat-routing) about how the immediate and mandatory flags impact message delivery in RabbitMQ.

In your case, since you have a consumer receiving messages, messages won't be returned even if the consumer never acks them.

D.